# How to sort array with user function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have php code, where occur sort, like this:

```
        j=0;
        while(...){
           ...
           $cancel_alarm_trusee[$j]['created'] = alarm['created'];
           ...
           j++;
        }

        function Compare($a, $b) {
           return $a['created'] < $b['created'];
        }

        usort($cancel_alarm_trusee, 'Compare');
```

How to do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby Has [**`Enumerable#sort`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [**`Enumerable#sort_by`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) also.Look those methods.

Example:

```
%w{apple pear fig}.sort_by { |word| word.length}
#=> ["fig", "pear", "apple"]
%w(rhea kea flea).sort  
#=> ["flea", "kea", "rhea"]
```